# Typing a letter in the middle of a string takes the cursor back to the end - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, textfield

I implemented a ChipInput component which when focused will behave a string and onBlur will be transformed into a Chip component with the chips introduced by a comma. All works well except for a single issue. When I type in multiple words, and I want to add a new letter in between, the cursor takes me to the end but I want the cursor to stay at the same position.

Could someone please help me out? Thanks.

[image]

This is my Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-8gg2w5?file=index.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because the `ChipInput` component is rerendered every time there is a change in the value of `name` in `index.tsx`.

One solution to this problem is to change the way `state` inside `ChipInput.tsx` is updated.

1. Firstly, remove the following `useEffect` code from `ChipInput.tsx`:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setState({
      inputValue: values,
      value: compact(map(split(values, separator), (i) => trim(i))),
    });
  }, [values]);
```

2. Change the initial value of `state` to:

```js
  const [state, setState] = useSetState<IChipInputState>({
    value: compact(map(split(values, separator), (i) => trim(i))),
    inputValue: values,
    isFocused: false,
  });
```

3. Modify the `setState` statement the `deleteChip` function to:

```js
    setState({
      value: newChipValues,
      inputValue: join(newChipValues, `${separator} `),
      isFocused: false,
    });
```

The `deleteChip` function would then look like:

```js
  const deleteChip = (chipValue: string): void => {
    const newChipValues = without(state.value, chipValue);
    setState({
      value: newChipValues,
      inputValue: join(newChipValues, `${separator} `),
      isFocused: false,
    });
    onHandleChange(join(newChipValues, `${separator} `), name);
  };
```

4. Finally add

```js
setState(prev => ({...prev, inputValue: onChangeValue }));
```

to the end of the `onInputChange` prop of the `Autocomplete` component in `ChipInput.tsx`. The `onInputChange` prop would then look like:

```js
      onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        let onChangeValue = newInputValue;
        if (acceptOnlyNumbers) {
          onChangeValue = replace(newInputValue, /[^\d, ]/, '');
        }
        if (acceptOnlyNumbersPercentage) {
          onChangeValue = replace(newInputValue, /[^\d,% ]/, '');
        }
        onHandleChange(onChangeValue, name);
        setState(prev => ({...prev, inputValue: onChangeValue }));
      }}
```